# Looking for the use of MEF in winform c#

Tags: c#, mef

i saw MEF become very popular now but i have no concept about MEF and its usage. so anyone tell me what is MEF & what kind of situation a developer use MEF. i was reading a article but things was not clear to me what is MEF. they use lots of attribute like import & export....what it does. what will be import & export by apps.

i read this article like
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/07/20/simple-example-using-managed-extensibility-framework-in-silverlight.aspx

it would be very helpful if some one discuss what is MEF and also its usage....where to use it. give me a tiny sample code for winform as a result i can understand its usage. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mef is dependency injection framework

Your differences with Unity

It discovers assemblies in a directory.

It uses XAP file download and assembly discovery.

It recomposes properties and collections as new types are discovered.
Page 31

It automatically exports derived types.

It is deployed with the .NET Framework.

First Step : export your module

```
[Export]
public class YourService : IYourService
{
.....

}
```

If you want inject this service in your clien, you can inject with (property injection)

```
public class Client
{

[Import]
public IYourService YouService;


......
}
```

Th third step is to register to MEF in catalog.

Comment: i hard MEF is something more than Dependency injection. so can u tell me what is the difference between DI & MEF. what more feature MEF provide.

Comment: MEF is considered also as dependency injection framework , the additional functionalities are : It discovers assemblies in a directory.

It uses XAP file download and assembly discovery.

It recomposes properties and collections as new types are discovered. Page 31

It automatically exports derived types.

It is deployed with the .NET Framework.

Comment: the sample code u gave not very clear to me. so one more request can u give me a function small code. thanks

Comment: the code is similar to this code without dependency injection :  puclic class Client { public IService Service; public Client() { this.Service = new Service();}}

Comment: what export attribute does. can i use export attribute at method level or i need to use it always at class level according to ur sample code. same way what import does.

Comment: Thomas you have here good article : http://hammett.castleproject.org/index.php/2009/02/mef-exporting-and-importing-methods/